Loop to input content into tabular
I'm trying to input files that represent rows of a table into a tabular environment using a loop, but I'm having trouble using input.
Here is a MWE of my code without using loops. I have files with rows for a table that I can loop over using numbers, and I define the command \tables with the path of the folder where I store these tables. I use csname with input to avoid issues with input being non-expandable (causing some issues when I add \midrule right after inputing a table the normal way).
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/r_1.tex"
\midrule
\csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/r_2.tex"
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

I have tried to do this with pgffor and forloop, but nothing works. Here is what I tried to do using pgffor:
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\midrule
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}{
    \csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/r_\x.tex"
    \midrule
}
\end{tabular}

The previous table doesn't compile. I have tried a simpler version with a regular input and without using booktabs, but it doesn't work either, even though the code works fine outside of a loop.
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}{
    \input{\tables/r_\x.tex}
}
\end{tabular}

Any ideas of what could I do here to fix this?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Each table cell is a scope on its own.
And each iteration of \foreach opens up its own local scope. (pgfmanual.pdf, section "88 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement" says: "Note that in each execution of ⟨commands⟩ the ⟨commands⟩ are put in a TeX group.")
Thus the scoping of table cells and the scoping of \foreach-iterations interfere badly:
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\midrule
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}{
    \csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/r_\x.tex"
    \midrule
}
\end{tabular}

is like
\begin{tabular}{cc}
% Begin of scope of 1st table cell in 1st row
% Begin of scope of 1st foreach-iteration
A 
% End of scope of 1st table cell  in 1st row
& 
[...]

You can see that, e.g., the end of scope of the 1st table cell in the 1st row is found while the scope of the 1st foreach-iteration is not closed yet.
You can use a \foreach-loop for gathering things in a token register:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, pgffor} 
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\newcommand\globaladdtoscratchtoks[1]{%
  \global\scratchtoks=\expandafter{\the\scratchtoks#1}%
}%

\begin{document}

\global\scratchtoks={}
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=1 \globaladdtoscratchtoks{\toprule}\fi
  \expandafter\globaladdtoscratchtoks\expandafter{%
    \csname @@input%
    \expandafter \expandafter 
    \expandafter              \endcsname
    \expandafter \expandafter
    \expandafter "%
    \expandafter \tables
    \expandafter /%
    \expandafter r%
    \expandafter_%
    \x.tex"%
  }%
  \ifnum\x=2 %
    \globaladdtoscratchtoks{\bottomrule}%
  \else
    \globaladdtoscratchtoks{\midrule}%
  \fi
}%
%\showthe\scratchtoks

\begin{tabular}{cc}\the\scratchtoks\end{tabular}

\end{document}


If you are comfortable with not sticking to pgf's \foreach but defining your own tail recuursive loop, e.g., using \numexpr, you can do as follows:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables


\newcommand\inputloop[2]{%
  \csname @\ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax>\numexpr(#2)\relax 
  gobble\else firstofone\fi\endcsname{%
    \csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/r_\the\numexpr(#1)\relax.tex"
    \ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax<\numexpr(#2)\relax \midrule \fi
    \expandafter\inputloop\expandafter{\the\numexpr((#1)+1)\relax}{#2}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\inputloop{1}{2}%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

If you like, you can change the argument-pattern of \inputloop as follows:
\inputloop{⟨lower bound for number-components of filenames⟩}
          {⟨upper bound for number-components of filenames⟩}
          {⟨file-path and/or filename-component at the left of the filename's number-component⟩}
          {⟨filename-component at the right of the filename's number-component⟩}
          {⟨tokens between \input-commands⟩}%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables


\newcommand\inputloop[5]{%
  \csname @\ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax>\numexpr(#2)\relax 
  gobble\else firstofone\fi\endcsname{%
    \csname @@input\endcsname "#3\the\numexpr(#1)\relax#4"
    \csname @\ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax<\numexpr(#2)\relax
    firstofone\else gobble\fi\endcsname{#5}%
    \expandafter\inputloop\expandafter{\the\numexpr((#1)+1)\relax}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  }%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\inputloop{1}{2}{\tables/r_}{.tex}{\midrule}%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thank you Ulrich, this is a great answer!
Do you think there is any way to add a third argument with the path+name for the table, or just the name? In my actual application I do this for several tables with different names, so I want to ideally define only one command to call them all.
I tried adding a third argument, and then editing this line:
\csname @@input\endcsname "\tables/#3\the\numexpr(#1)\relax.tex"
After I added this to the loop:  \inputloop{1}{2}{r_}%, but it doesn't work. I also tried putting the \tables into the third argument, but that also didn't work.

@NicolasSuarez I just did an edit and added a variant where things before and behind the number-component of the filename, e.g., filepath, are to be specified via macro arguments. Via a 5th argument you specify tokens to be inserted between \input-commands - e.g., \midrule.

Thank you so much Ulrich, that solution is all I needed!

Here I use an approach with readarray.  Note, for convenience, I changed filenames to remain in the working directory only.
Here, I show how to loop through a list of files identified by
% LIST OF FILE IDENTIFIERS
\def\filelist{1,2,X}

In this case, since the files already have the tabular formatting contained within, I only need to read the file contents into a \def.
Here is the MWE:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_X.tex}
\today & ZZ \\
P & Q \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, readarray,listofitems} 
\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtotoks[1]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter{#1}}
\readarraysepchar{}
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables

% LIST OF FILE IDENTIFIERS
\def\filelist{1,2,X}
% READ FILE CONTENTS INTO VARIABLES NAMED \r_<identifier>
\readlist\myfiles{\filelist}
\foreachitem\z\in\myfiles[]{%
  \def\tmp{\readdef{r_\z.tex}}
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\csname r_\z\endcsname}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
% ACCUMULATE TYPESET ARRAY TOKENS
\foreachitem\z\in\myfiles[]{%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\addtotoks{\midrule}\fi
  \xaddtotoks{\csname r_\z\endcsname}%
}%
% SET THE TOKENS IN THE TABULAR
\the\mytoks
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


If one wished to avoid placing the & and \\ formatting within the data files themselves, readarray can handles that, as well.  However, in this case, the file information would have to be read into 2-D arrays, so that the tabular formatting could be added between cells, by redefining \typesetrowsepchar and \typesetcolsepchar appropriately.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_1.tex}
A, B
C, D
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_2.tex}
1, 2
3, 4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{r_X.tex}
\today, ZZ
P, Q
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, readarray,listofitems} 
\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtotoks[1]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter{#1}}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\newcommand{\tables}{Folder} %Path for tables

% LIST OF FILE IDENTIFIERS
\def\filelist{1,2,X}
% READ FILE CONTENTS INTO ARRAYS NAMED 
%   \myarray_<identifier>[<row>,<column>]
\readlist\myfiles{\filelist}
\foreachitem\z\in\myfiles[]{%
  \def\tmp{\readdef{r_\z.tex}}
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\csname r_\z\endcsname}
  \expandafter\readarray\csname r_\z\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname myarray\z\endcsname[-,\ncols]
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
% ACCUMULATE TYPESET ARRAY TOKENS
\foreachitem\z\in\myfiles[]{%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\addtotoks{\\\midrule}\fi
  \addtotoks{\expandafter\typesetarray\csname myarray}%
  \xaddtotoks{\z\endcsname}%
}%
% SET THE TOKENS IN THE TABULAR
\the\mytoks\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


There is no problem when OpTeX is used, because \fornum and \foreach from OpTeX runs independently of TeX groups and they are expandable.
\createfile {r_1.tex}
A & B \cr
C & D \cr
\endfile

\createfile {r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \cr
3 & 4 \cr
\endfile


\def\toprule{\crcr\noalign{\hrule height1pt}}
\let\bottomrule=\toprule
\def\midrule{\crcr\noalign{\hrule}}

\table{cc}{
   \toprule
   \fornum 1..2 \do{\input r_#1 \ifnum#1<2 \midrule \else \bottomrule \fi}
}
\bye


Load the files in a variable, put them together and deliver them at once, with \midrule between them.
Loading a file is done with \file_get:nnNTF so we can also protect against missing files.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketablefromfiles}{O{.}m}
 {% #1 = optional path, #2 = list of file names
  \suarez_maketable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq
\tl_new:N \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \suarez_maketable:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \file_get:nnNTF { #1/##1 } {} \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl
     {% file exists
      \seq_put_right:NV \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl
     }
     {% file doesn't exist
      \msg_error:nnn { suarez/maketable } { file-not-exist } { ##1 }
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq { \\ }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq { \midrule }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { suarez/maketable } { file-not-exist }
 {
  Non~existing~file~#1
 }
 {
  The~file~you~requested~doesn't~exist.~Added~\tl_to_str:n { \\ }~to~avoid~errors
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\tables}{Folder}

\begin{document}

% with the explicit path
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\maketablefromfiles[Folder]{r_1,r_2}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% with the macro for the path; also error shown
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\maketablefromfiles[\tables]{r_1,r_2,r_3}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

The second example shows you can use a macro in the “path” argument. I show also what happens if you request a file that doesn't exist. Of course, if you remove r_3 in the second argument, the output is the same as in the first example.

The error as shown on the console:
! Package suarez/maketable Error: Non existing file r_3

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.66 \maketablefromfiles[\tables]{r_1,r_2,r_3}

? h

The file you requested doesn't exist. Added \\ to avoid errors

?

A slightly different version, where the separation between the parts is optional (default \midrule).
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_1.tex}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Folder/r_2.tex}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketablefromfiles}{O{.}mO{\midrule}}
 {% #1 = optional path, #2 = list of file names, #3 = optional separator
  \suarez_maketable:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq
\tl_new:N \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \suarez_maketable:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \file_get:nnNTF { #1/##1 } {} \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl
     {% file exists
      \seq_put_right:NV \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq \l__suarez_maketable_tmp_tl
     }
     {% file doesn't exist
      \msg_error:nnn { suarez/maketable } { file-not-exist } { ##1 }
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq { \\ }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__suarez_maketable_body_seq { #3 }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { suarez/maketable } { file-not-exist }
 {
  Non~existing~file~#1
 }
 {
  The~file~you~requested~doesn't~exist.~Added~\tl_to_str:n { \\ }~to~avoid~errors
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\tables}{Folder}

\begin{document}

% with the explicit path
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\maketablefromfiles[Folder]{r_1,r_2}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% with the macro for the path
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\maketablefromfiles[\tables]{r_1,r_2}[\addlinespace]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


